# How to SQL Query to select unsubscribed and held?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

My SQL is a little rusty, but this query should be simple enough. I'm trying to get a list of all the emails in the all subscriber list that have a status of "unsubscribed" or "held" in the system. The following query errors on "_Subscribers is not a known data extension or system data view." I'm sure I don't have the table name correct, but I'm not sure what it is or how to find it.

```
SELECT EmailAddress, SubscriberKey, [Status]
FROM _Subscribers
WHERE [status] is ('unsubscribed','held')
```

Comment: you can refer this question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96543/subscriber-object-status-active-and-unsubscribed-from-all-subscribers

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting that error, I assume you are trying to access the _Subscribers Data View from a child Business Unit. Try the following (and note the `IN` operator):

```sql
SELECT EmailAddress, SubscriberKey, Status
FROM ENT.[_Subscribers]
WHERE [Status] IN ('unsubscribed','held')
```

Comment: Thank you Eliot. I'm still getting this error: An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: ENT.[_Subscribers] is not a known data extension or system data view. You can only query existing data extensions or system data views.

Comment: Not all SFMC accounts have the Enterprise tables enabled via Query Activities, You may want to contact support.

Answer (score 0):

Eliot answer is correct but you try this

```
SELECT EmailAddress, SubscriberKey, Status
FROM _Subscribers
WHERE Status IN ('unsubscribed','held')
```

Comment: Thanks. Again, I'm getting this same error:

An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: _Subscribers is not a known data extension or system data view. You can only query existing data extensions or system data views.

Comment: It's rare, but I've seen accounts where you need support to activate the Data Views for querying. Are you able to query any other data views? Try: "SELECT * FROM _Open" as an example

Comment: Nope. How do I turn on data views for querying? I guess that's step #1 :)

Comment: Create a case with SFMC support and they should be able to enable it in short time. If you've never made a case before, do as follows: Hover over name at the top right of the screen within Marketing Cloud -> Salesforce Help & Training -> Select Contact Support / Create a Case at bottom right of screen -> General Email Functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also.

```sql
select j.JobID ,u.EventDate, s.EmailAddress, s.SubscriberKey
From _job j Join _Unsubscribe u on j.JobID = u.JobID
Join _Subscribers s on u.SubscriberID = s.SubscriberID
Where u.IsUnique = 1 And u.Eventdate > dateadd (d,-30,getdate())
```